# Showing list of items as I input every single text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

Before anything else i just want to apologize for my bad english. I don't know how to say it and I had been stock searching on how can I `get the list of items as I input every single text`. for example I want to search the name Printer. As I enter the first letter which is `P` all items which start with `P` will show and so on. Can someone please directed me on this tutorial? or maybe can help me on doing this one?

Feel free to edit my question and please be kind to a beginner like me. Thank you

Im using a `winform`

Comment: We need a little more clarification. What UI are you using? WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net, a custom library? Generally any text box will have some sort of change event/binding that you can subscribe/bind to.

Comment: I'm using a winform

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, the `TextBox` control has a `KeyUp` event that you can subscribe to. I am assuming that you have a `TextBox` called `txtSearch` on your form. Attach an event handler to this event using the designer or the Load event in your code-behind:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSearch.KeyUp += txtSearch_KeyUp;
}
```

Then create the event handler and use the value of the `txtSearch` to fetch data/filter etc.

```
private void txtSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var searchText = txtSearch.Text;

    //TODO: Do something with the search string
}
```

Comment: What could be my statement in my access database?

Comment: would it be easy if I use combo box instead of a textbox?

Comment: You can use either, depending on what you want to do. A ComboBox will give you auto-complete capabilities. Your question is too broad to answer here. What have you tried?

Comment: To connect to access, search "C# ODBC connection to Access database". There is a lot of information available there.

Answer (score 0):

step 1)  On Form Load Get Data From Database and Fill in Datatable dtAutocomplete

step 2) call this method  on form load

```
 CompleteSource(dtAutocomplete, txtCity, "City");//(datatable , your textboxname , database feild name you want to bind like printername)



  public void CompleteSource(DataTable dtsource, TextBox txtname, string fieldname)
            {
                AutoCompleteStringCollection autoitem = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtsource.Rows)
            {
                autoitem.Add(dr[fieldname].ToString());
            }

            txtname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            txtname.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            txtname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoitem;
        }
```